# Adding image generated from another library as inset in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, image, matplotlib, plot, insets

I've generated a network figure using `vedo` library and I'm trying to add this as an inset to a figure generated in `matplotlib`

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from vedo import *
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox


G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=10, m=15, seed=1)
nxpos = nx.spring_layout(G, dim=3, seed=1)

nxpts = [nxpos[pt] for pt in sorted(nxpos)]
nx_lines = [(nxpts[i], nxpts[j]) for i, j in G.edges()]

pts = Points(nxpts, r=12)
edg = Lines(nx_lines).lw(2)

# node values
values = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [30, 80, 10, 79, 70, 60, 75, 78, 65, 10],
          [1, .30, .10, .79, .70, .60, .75, .78, .65, .90]]
time = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2]  # in seconds

vplt = Plotter(N=1)
pts1 = pts.cmap('Blues', values[0])
vplt.show(
    pts1, edg,
    axes=False,
    bg='white',
    at=0,
    interactive=False,
    zoom=1.5
).screenshot("network.png")

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(
    [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3],
    'go-',
    label='line 1',
    linewidth=2
 )

arr_img = vplt.screenshot(returnNumpy=True, scale=1)
im = OffsetImage(arr_img, zoom=0.25)
ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (1, 0), xycoords='axes fraction', box_alignment=(1.1, -0.1), frameon=False)
ax.add_artist(ab)
plt.show()
ax.figure.savefig(
    "output.svg",
    transparent=True,
    dpi=600,
    bbox_inches="tight"
)
```

There resolution of the image in the inset is too low. Suggestions on how to add the inset without loss of resolution will be really helpful.

EDIT:
The answer posted below works for adding a 2D network, but I am still looking for ways that will be useful for adding a 3D network in the inset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with `vedo` but the general procedure would be to create an `inset_axis` and plot the image with `imshow`. However, your code is using `networkx` which has `matplotlib` bindings and you can directly do this without `vedo`

EDIT: code edited for 3d plotting

[image]

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=10, m=15, seed=1)
nxpos = nx.spring_layout(G, dim=3, seed=1)

nxpts = [nxpos[pt] for pt in sorted(nxpos)]
nx_lines = [(nxpts[i], nxpts[j]) for i, j in G.edges()]

# node values
values = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [30, 80, 10, 79, 70, 60, 75, 78, 65, 10],
          [1, .30, .10, .79, .70, .60, .75, .78, .65, .90]]
time = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2]  # in seconds


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(
    [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3],
    'go-',
    label='line 1',
    linewidth=2
 )

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import (Axes3D)
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox
rect = [.6, 0, .5, .5]
bbox = Bbox.from_bounds(*rect)
inax = fig.add_axes(bbox, projection = '3d')
# inax = add_inset_axes(, 
#                       ax_target = ax, 
#                       fig = fig, projection = '3d')

# inax.axis('off')


# set angle
angle = 25
inax.view_init(10, angle)

# hide axes, make transparent
# inax.set_facecolor('none')
# inax.grid('off')
import numpy as np

# plot 3d
seen = set()
for i, j in G.edges():
    x = np.stack((nxpos[i], nxpos[j]))
    inax.plot(*x.T, color = 'k')
    if i not in seen:
        inax.scatter(*x[0], color = 'skyblue')
        seen.add(i)
    if j not in seen:
        inax.scatter(*x[1], color = "skyblue")
        seen.add(j)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you., could you please suggest how to add 3D network plots inset? As far as I know, networkx creates only 2D network plots.

Comment: Code edited for 3d plotting. Networkx indeed does not allow for edges to be plotted in 3d, nodes can be plotted in any dimensions. the code above reflects 3d plotting.

Comment: I added a [pull request](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/4489/files) for a more rigorous fix. Thanks!